# Why does gii, when creating CRUD, change my view path from ldopt to ld-opt?

Tags: php, yii2, gii

Is ldopt a reserved word in yii/php for some reason.

The actual table is called `LdOpt`. So the model generated is also called `LdOpt`

Then when generating the CRUD I set model class to `app\models\LdOpt` and Search Model class to `app\models\LdOptSearch` and controller to `app\controllers\LdOptController`, finally leaving the View Path empty

But gii changes path from expected `ldopt` to `ld-opt` as in preview view

```
Code          File                  Action  
controllers   /LdOptController.php  create  
models        /LdOptSearch.php      create  
views         /ld-opt/_form.php     create  
views         /ld-opt/_search.php   create  
views         /ld-opt/create.php    create  
views         /ld-opt/index.php     create  
views         /ld-opt/update.php    create  
views         /ld-opt/view.php      create
```

Just wondering why it did it because never paid attention to file name and just generated them and wasted some time with route `?r=ldopt/index` etc before I looked at files on disk.

Also as an experiment I tried moving the directory back to `ldopt` and it causes a 404 not found in yii

Comment: Also just noticed it did this with a table called `CmdtyAct` - changing view path to `cmdty-act`. Is this related to the camel case of table names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the Yii2 pathname for controller convention ..

> Controller Class Naming
>
> Controller class names can be derived from controller IDs according to
>   the following procedure:
>
> Turn the first letter in each word separated by hyphens into upper 
>   case. Note that if the controller ID contains slashes, this rule only
>   applies to the part after the last slash in the ID.
>    Remove hyphens and replace any forward slashes with backward slashes.
>    Append the suffix Controller.
>    Prepend the controller namespace.
>
> The following are some examples, assuming the controller namespace
>   takes the default value app\controllers:
>
> ```
> article becomes app\controllers\ArticleController;
> post-comment becomes app\controllers\PostCommentController;
> admin/post-comment becomes app\controllers\admin\PostCommentController;
> adminPanels/post-comment becomes app\controllers\adminPanels\PostCommentController.
> ```

the info above are from  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#controller-class-naming